# Need advice about transfering HTTP_REFERER to another page

Tags: php, variables, session-variables, http-referer

So I'm currently trying to save page1.php's `HTTP_REFFERER` as a variable and transfer that variable to another page. I've tried using `$_SESSION[]` and `$_COOKIES[]` methods but it didn't work. `page2.php` shows referrer as `page.php`.

Any suggestions?

page1.php :

```
<?php session_start();
$variable1 = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$_SESSION['ref'] = $variable1;
```

page2.php :

```
<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['ref'] = $variable1;
echo $variable1; ?>
```

Comment: Show us some code. Most probably you did something wrong... if you store it in session it shouldn't change...

Comment: page1.php : <?php
session_start();
$variable1 = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
$_SESSION['ref'] = $variable1; page2.php :<?php session_start();
$_SESSION['ref'] = $variable1;
echo $variable1; ?>

Comment: Try `$variable1 = $_SESSION['ref']` in page2.

Comment: Well you're doing it wrong, you're re-assigning value to session variable on page 2, while you should get the value from it, not assigning it

Comment: Thank you andrewsi and Bartdude for quick response! It really worked! One more time thanks! :)

Comment: just to be sure, you have a "page0.php" where there is a link to page1 right ? If you access directly to page1, `HTTP_REFERER` will be empty .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted the variable and the value in your 2nd page

```
<?php
session_start();
$variable1 = $_SESSION['ref'];
echo $variable1;
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is a predefined env variable. To access stored variable use for example $_SESSION['HTTP_REFERER'] on page2.php

Answer (score 0):

In **page1.php**, make sure to end the code correctly:

```
<?php session_start();

  $variable1 = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

  $_SESSION['ref'] = $variable1;

?>
```

In **page2.php** just `print_r` the `$_SESSION['ref']` or assign it to a variable and then use `echo`.

**Also** the order of the variables is incorrect, should be:

```
$variable1 = $_SESSION['ref'];
```

HTH.